# Show/Hide Table Rows based on Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show or hide 3 table rows based on one check box. The 3 table rows should hide in the first place. It should only show when user has checked the box. I have seen other people's work and tried doing it.

However, it is not working in my web page. On top of that, the 3 table rows are shown when page is loaded. It should be hidden in the first place and shown when Visit checkbox has been checked.

I have tried placing the JS codes at the top or bottom of my web page.

Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/pbtbS/22/

My HTML page

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="LABEL">Visit</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="visit" id="visit" onclick="showHide()" /></td>
</tr>


<tr id="visitDate">
  <td class="LABEL">Visit Date</td>
  <td><select name="day" class="LABEL" id="day">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Day</option>
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
    <option value="04">4</option>
    <option value="05">5</option>
    <option value="06">6</option>
    <option value="07">7</option>
    <option value="08">8</option>
    <option value="09">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
  </select>
    <select name="month" class="LABEL" id="month">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Month</option>
      <option value="01">January</option>
      <option value="02">February</option>
      <option value="03">March</option>
      <option value="04">April</option>
      <option value="05">May</option>
      <option value="06">June</option>
      <option value="07">July</option>
      <option value="08">August</option>
      <option value="09">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="year" class="LABEL" id="year">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Year</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr id="visitSTime">
  <td class="LABEL">Start Time</td>
  <td><select name="Hr" class="LABEL" id="Hr">
    <option value="" selected="selected">HH</option>
      <option value="00">00</option>
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="17">17</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="21">21</option>
      <option value="22">22</option>
      <option value="23">23</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
  </select>
    :
    <select name="Min" class="LABEL" id="Min">
      <option value="" selected="selected">MM</option>
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="17">17</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="21">21</option>
      <option value="22">22</option>
      <option value="23">23</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="26">26</option>
      <option value="27">27</option>
      <option value="28">28</option>
      <option value="29">29</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="31">31</option>
      <option value="32">32</option>
      <option value="33">33</option>
      <option value="34">34</option>
      <option value="35">35</option>
      <option value="36">36</option>
      <option value="37">37</option>
      <option value="38">38</option>
      <option value="39">39</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
      <option value="41">41</option>
      <option value="42">42</option>
      <option value="43">43</option>
      <option value="44">44</option>
      <option value="45">45</option>
      <option value="46">46</option>
      <option value="47">47</option>
      <option value="48">48</option>
      <option value="49">49</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="51">51</option>
      <option value="52">52</option>
      <option value="53">53</option>
      <option value="54">54</option>
      <option value="55">55</option>
      <option value="56">56</option>
      <option value="57">57</option>
      <option value="58">58</option>
      <option value="59">59</option>
      <option value="60">60</option>
    </select>
    :
    <select name="Sec" class="LABEL" id="Sec">
      <option value="" selected="selected">SS</option>
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="17">17</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="21">21</option>
      <option value="22">22</option>
      <option value="23">23</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="26">26</option>
      <option value="27">27</option>
      <option value="28">28</option>
      <option value="29">29</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="31">31</option>
      <option value="32">32</option>
      <option value="33">33</option>
      <option value="34">34</option>
      <option value="35">35</option>
      <option value="36">36</option>
      <option value="37">37</option>
      <option value="38">38</option>
      <option value="39">39</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
      <option value="41">41</option>
      <option value="42">42</option>
      <option value="43">43</option>
      <option value="44">44</option>
      <option value="45">45</option>
      <option value="46">46</option>
      <option value="47">47</option>
      <option value="48">48</option>
      <option value="49">49</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="51">51</option>
      <option value="52">52</option>
      <option value="53">53</option>
      <option value="54">54</option>
      <option value="55">55</option>
      <option value="56">56</option>
      <option value="57">57</option>
      <option value="58">58</option>
      <option value="59">59</option>
      <option value="60">60</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr id="visitETime">
  <td class="LABEL">End Time</td>
  <td><select name="Hr2" class="LABEL" id="Hr2">
    <option value="" selected="selected">HH</option>
      <option value="00">00</option>
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="17">17</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="21">21</option>
      <option value="22">22</option>
      <option value="23">23</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
  </select>
    :
    <select name="Min2" class="LABEL" id="Min2">
      <option value="" selected="selected">MM</option>
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="17">17</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="21">21</option>
      <option value="22">22</option>
      <option value="23">23</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="26">26</option>
      <option value="27">27</option>
      <option value="28">28</option>
      <option value="29">29</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="31">31</option>
      <option value="32">32</option>
      <option value="33">33</option>
      <option value="34">34</option>
      <option value="35">35</option>
      <option value="36">36</option>
      <option value="37">37</option>
      <option value="38">38</option>
      <option value="39">39</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
      <option value="41">41</option>
      <option value="42">42</option>
      <option value="43">43</option>
      <option value="44">44</option>
      <option value="45">45</option>
      <option value="46">46</option>
      <option value="47">47</option>
      <option value="48">48</option>
      <option value="49">49</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="51">51</option>
      <option value="52">52</option>
      <option value="53">53</option>
      <option value="54">54</option>
      <option value="55">55</option>
      <option value="56">56</option>
      <option value="57">57</option>
      <option value="58">58</option>
      <option value="59">59</option>
      <option value="60">60</option>
    </select>
    :
    <select name="Sec2" class="LABEL" id="Sec2">
      <option value="" selected="selected">SS</option>
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="17">17</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="21">21</option>
      <option value="22">22</option>
      <option value="23">23</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="26">26</option>
      <option value="27">27</option>
      <option value="28">28</option>
      <option value="29">29</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="31">31</option>
      <option value="32">32</option>
      <option value="33">33</option>
      <option value="34">34</option>
      <option value="35">35</option>
      <option value="36">36</option>
      <option value="37">37</option>
      <option value="38">38</option>
      <option value="39">39</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
      <option value="41">41</option>
      <option value="42">42</option>
      <option value="43">43</option>
      <option value="44">44</option>
      <option value="45">45</option>
      <option value="46">46</option>
      <option value="47">47</option>
      <option value="48">48</option>
      <option value="49">49</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="51">51</option>
      <option value="52">52</option>
      <option value="53">53</option>
      <option value="54">54</option>
      <option value="55">55</option>
      <option value="56">56</option>
      <option value="57">57</option>
      <option value="58">58</option>
      <option value="59">59</option>
      <option value="60">60</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript Codings

```
function showHide() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('#visit').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#visitDate').show();
        $('#visitSTime').show();
        $('#visitETime').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#visitDate').hide();
        $('#visitSTime').hide();
        $('#visitETime').hide();
    }
});
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the onclick function from checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="visit" id="visit" />
```

And your function should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#visit').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('#visitDate').show();
            $('#visitSTime').show();
            $('#visitETime').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#visitDate').hide();
            $('#visitSTime').hide();
            $('#visitETime').hide();
        }
    });
    });
```

Please see fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/pbtbS/25/

Comment: Hi, the jsfiddle redirects me to a collaboration page. I tried inserting the above function to my coding but it still didn't work.

Comment: Besides the above js function, is there an alternative to achieve the result I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
$('#visit').change();
```

after binding `$("#visit")` to its change event in `$(document).ready()`.

**edit**

in addition, don't write the `$(document).ready()` inside another function. It must work.

Comment: Hi, I have remove the first line $(document).ready() but it still didn't work. Is there an alternative to get result of show/hide table rows based on checkbox?

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. you have to remove the wrapper function function showHide(), not the $(document).ready(). I tried it in my computer, it worked. and don't forget $('#visit').change(); inside the $(document).ready().